# The blind leading the blind

Tags: discussion

Of late (past 3 months, perhaps) I feel I'm noticing an increasing tendency for newbie questions to be answered more by newbies than by experienced developers.  To an extent this is goodness, but when the answers contain serious errors and they're not corrected (which often the case) it would seem to be a problem.

It might just be my personal perception, of course -- has anyone else noticed this?

Comment: You just downvote, closevote and delete based on content.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I didn't ask how to handle the situation, I asked if it's getting more common.

Comment: May be you can ask the database to give a proof for this perception?

Comment: It does seem opinion based, but yes, I have sort of noticed this as well.  Along with "Wow your [sic] brilliant!" accolades for answers which are *not*.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ as a starting point, [here is a query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/281415?StartDate=2015.01.01&EndDate=2015.01.31#graph) of log10(reputation) of answers on questions of users who have less than 200 rep for January 2015. Which is probably a little bit more helpful (given reading log graphs) than the [rounded version](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/281430#graph)  - either way, starters for data.  And yes, it does indeed look the way that Hot Licks is describing at first glance..

Comment: @HotLicks Shouldn't the title read _"The blind leading the lame"_ BTW?

Comment: @MichaelT - Given that reputation accrues over time, I don't know that any query based on reputation is going to provide useful historic information about the percentage of questions being answered by new users. New users in 2010 will not appear to be new users when we look back to their first answers now. Going by the age of accounts at the time they answered a question would be the only sensible way to do this.

Comment: Stack Overflow has been accused of being the "blind leading the blind" since near its beginning (original blog post appears lost to the winds): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature/3714#3714

Comment: @BradLarson the creation date for the question is in the range of January 2015.  And yes, that is a problem, though I don't suspect that there has been *that* much accrual of reputation for users who now have less than 200 rep and asked or answered a question in January.

Comment: @BradLarson:  [here's an archive of the blog in question](https://web.archive.org/web/20080912074147/http://blogging-harmful.blogspot.com/2008/08/stack-overflow-blind-leading-blind.html).  In retrospect it's pretty clear what tone they're taking and how optimistic (or pessimistic) they are of the site during its beta phase.

Comment: Low SO reputation does not necessarily imply lack of experience or knowledge. It just means the person is new to SO.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: the quality of both question and answer will tell us that. Hot Licks is not concerned about new, but already experienced, users. I have been pleasantly surprised before by new users giving perfect, well-thought out answers. ...Not often, but it does happen.

Answer (score 5):

Going from the [rounded version](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/281430#graph) of the query that I mentioned in the comments... I present you a chart of the sum of the questions asked by users less than 200 reputation where the highest rep answer is from a user on the X axis...

[image]

There were about 100k questions asked (98167) by users in the category in the month of January 2015.  The median for this graph is in the 2300 rep bucket. Half the answers were from users with more than this rep, half with lower.

I will point out that digging into too far in history will cause issues with the gradual accrual of data.  It is non-trivial to determine what the reputation of someone in the past would be.  That is why this is for the month of January which isn't too much older than the data dump itself.

As this is working with rounded data, that gap between 1 and 100 is kind of stark, but without digging into more powerful tools, I'd rather work with ~800 rows than... a much larger number.

---

There *is* a flaw in this query in that reputation doesn't necessarily correspond to skill.  An approach to modify the query to.  Another approach to try to refine this (with more subqueries) would be to instead of ranking users based on reputation, rank users by the mean (or better yet, the [inter quartile mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_mean) of answer scores.

This would partially address two flaws in the query above:

- Question rep counts too
- Lots of 1 score answers can add up to a bit of reputation

Comment: That proposed refinement pre-supposes that experience corresponds somewhat with popularity.

Comment: It's better than the current query. The suggestion of using the IQM should help alleviate the bias to wildly popular answers and seek to find the bread and butter answers the person gives. Now, if those are also popular, that's an issue too - I'll call that the Skeet problem. There is also the data that is hidden from data.se, the blind leading the blind in deleted questions. However, this isn't meant to be ***the*** answer but rather a staring point point for digging into the data that exists for the question of are low rep users getting poor quality answers.